# Regex matches space between characters

Tags: java, regex, rubular

I have this regex

```
(\((-?\d+.\d+\s?-?\d+.\d+,?)+\))*
```

that seems to be matching the space between characters at the very beginning of the string along with the parts that I would like to match.How can I change my regex to not match these as it causes empty arrays when converting to JSON?

Comment: Do you mean space between characters?  Or do you mean empty string?  I'm pretty sure that this regexp doesn't match spaces, but it certainly matches the empty string, because of the `*` at the end.

Comment: Please provide some input and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` (one or more) instead of `*` (zero or more)

`(\((-?\d+.\d+\s?-?\d+.\d+,?)+\))+`